# ViewWillTransitionToSize broke in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using viewWillTransitionToSize to adjust my slideout menu when I rotate the device, however it seems to be broken in Swift 3? Can anyone solve this for me? My code looks like this:

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
            _ in

            let controller = self.revealViewController().rightViewController

            var frame = controller?.view.frame
            frame?.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.toolBar.frame.size.height - (UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden ? 0 : 20)
            controller?.view.frame = frame!
        })
    }
```

It seems like it doesn't get called when I rotate the device?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured out what the problems was, the changes the migration to swift 3 made was not proper, and the function should look like this:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: {
            _ in

            let controller = self.revealViewController().rightViewController

            var frame = controller?.view.frame
            frame?.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.toolBar.frame.size.height - (UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden ? 0 : 20)
            controller?.view.frame = frame!
        })

    }
```

Comment: For future reference, am I right that the only thing that changed was the `override` keyword?

Comment: @zneak Notice the method signature changes.

Comment: API declaration History:
`func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`
 
To 

`func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`

Comment: `viewWillTransition` is working the opposite way. While the device is rotated to Landscape, it shows as Portrait. Is it only me, or anyone else has experienced this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632424/check-landscape-portrait-orientation-in-an-imessage-app-extension